# Batch process aligning multiple rasters in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, batch, cell-size

I would like to know if there´s a way to run a batch process that consists in aligning (changing cell size from 10 to 20 in Sentinel 2 imagery) in QGIS 3.4?

I need to resample band #8 (resolution 10m) from several images to combine them with other bands with 20m cell size, so it would be annoying to do it individually for each image.

I think this would be possible programming it with Python console, but don't know so much Python to even consider it. What are other alternatives?

Comment: Consider using the QGIS Graphical Modeler, fairly easy to use and should be possible to accomplish what you'd like.

Comment: the FORCE framework can accomplish this quite easily: https://www.uni-trier.de/index.php?id=63673

Comment: Most of the tools in the processing toolbox can be run in "batch processing" mode. Right-click on the tool name.